# Laravel : Call to a member function send() on string on Listeners

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I am trying to do `pushnotification` when a new user signup.So I created `events` called `MemberNotificationEvents`, when I fired an event `event(new MemberNotificationEvent($UserDetails));` on my `signUpController` flow is completely going but on the `MemberNotificationListener` a `public function handle(MemberNotificationEvent $event)`  return error that :

> Call to a member function send() on string

I put full code of `MemberNotificationListener` :

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\MemberNotificationEvent;
use App\Services\PushNotificationService;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class MemberNotificationListener implements ShouldQueue
{
private $pushNotificationService;
/**
 * Create the event listener.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{

    $this->pushNotificationService = PushNotificationService::class;
}

 private function getMessageBody($username)
{
    return "Awesome! Welcome " . $username . " to IDM";
}

/**
 * Handle the event.
 *
 * @param  object  $event
 * @return void
 */
public function handle(MemberNotificationEvent $event)
{

    $username = $event->UserDetails->name; 
    $message = $this->getMessageBody($username);

    $this->pushNotificationService->send($event,['body' => $message]); // throw error
}
}
```

What is the problem in my code?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with this line:

```
$this->pushNotificationService = PushNotificationService::class;
```

When you do `SomeClass::class`, it means you supply the class name - not the actual class.

Hence, when you later do `$this->pushNotificationService->send(...)`, the push notification service is just the class name and not the service class.

The second part of the problem is that you need an actual object to put in there. Laravel can inject it for you in the constructor, and then you can supply it. Like this:

```
public function __construct(PushNotificationService $service)
{
    $this->pushNotificationService = $service;
}
```

Comment: Yup, Joel is right, please remove the ::class to make it work.

Comment: @Rob can you please edit my code where can i change?

Comment: @Joel Hinz hello guyz r u there ?

Comment: @Javed You just need to remove the `::class`

Comment: @JoelHinz it returns `Use of undefined constant PushNotificationService - assumed 'PushNotificationService`

Comment: Sorry, didn't look beyond the most obvious error. Please check my edited answer.

Comment: @JoelHinz `Class App\\Services\\PushNotificationService does not exist`

Comment: Check your namespacing then. C'mon, you need to do a little work yourself, you can't just expect to be spoonfed every line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171534/discussion-between-javed-and-joel-hinz).